# Smart Card (SIM Card), connect to stm32 via USART

Tags: stm32, embedded, uart, sim, smart-card

After get ATR and send PTS, I tried send APDU, but response always the same as APDU which has been sent.
I tried to change the frequency for USART (clock) and baud rate, after I tried to change PTS value for ETU and T=0, but always same result.

[image]

**Schematic:**
[image]

**Answer from Smart Card:**
[image]

**main code:**

```c
int main(void)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    /* USER CODE END 1 */

    /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
    // uint8_t res2[8] ={0x80,0xCA,0x9F,0x17,0x00};
    /* USER CODE END Init */

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART2_UART_Init();
    MX_USART1_SMARTCARD_Init();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    /* USER CODE END 2 */
    uint8_t response[50];
    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    HAL_StatusTypeDef convention;
    uint8_t h = 97;
    uint8_t first_request[10] = {0xA0,0xA4 ,0x00 ,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    uint8_t second[4] = {0x7F,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    uint8_t second2[5] = {0x00,0xB0,0x00,0x00,0x07};
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        response[i] = 0x00;
    }
    uint8_t response2[8] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    uint8_t send[6] = {0xFF, 0x00,0xFF,0x00,0x00,0x00};

    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, response,1);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12, 0);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_13, 0);
    HAL_Delay(100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_13, 1);

    //  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_14, 1);
    HAL_Delay(15);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12, 1);
    HAL_SMARTCARD_Receive(&hsc1, response, 30, 100);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, response, 24, 100);
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        response[i] = 0x00;
    }
    HAL_Delay(20);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, send, 6, 100);
    HAL_SMARTCARD_Transmit(&hsc1, send, 4,100);
    HAL_SMARTCARD_Receive(&hsc1, response, 30, 100);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, response, 8, 100);

    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, first_request, 8, 100);
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        response[i] = 0x00;
    }
    HAL_SMARTCARD_Transmit(&hsc1, first_request, 5,100);
    HAL_SMARTCARD_Receive(&hsc1, response, 30, 100);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, response, 5, 100);
    HAL_SMARTCARD_Transmit(&hsc1, second, 2,100);
    HAL_SMARTCARD_Receive(&hsc1, response2, 30, 100);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, second, 4, 100);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,response2,5,100);
    while (1)
    {

    }
    /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Comment: So what kind of hardware  and connections you have between STM32 and the smart card?

Comment: stm32 it direct connection to smart card, PA9(USART1_TX) and PA8(USART_CK) soldered to I/O(7-pin) and CLK(3-pin)  from smart card and send/recive hex value via HAL_SMARTCARD_Transmit()/HAL_SMARTCARD_Receive()

Comment: So no power supply for the card? No pull-up for open-drain bi-dir comms? Show the schematics, the problem may not even be in the code.

Comment: I edited my question, PB12 and PB13 will be set on high level. after i get ATR from smart card. If you need other details, please ask me.